# PDF of random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have the following random variable:

$$ \xi_{\omega} = \begin{cases} 2 \omega & 0 \leq \omega \leq \frac{1}{2} \\ 2 \omega - 1 & \frac{1}{2} \lt \omega \leq 1 \end{cases}$$

How to find its [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)?

Comment: @kglr I need function F(x)=P(\xi < x)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that $\omega\sim U(0,1)$. We can write \begin{align*}F_X(x)&=P(X\le x)=P(X\le x\mid \omega\le 0.5)\cdot P(\omega\le 0.5)+P(X\le x\mid \omega>0.5)\cdot P(\omega>0.5)\\&=P(2\omega\le x)\cdot F_{\omega}(0.5)+P(2\omega-1\le x)\cdot (1-P(\omega\le 0.5)) \\&=P\left(\omega\le \frac{x}{2}\right)F_{\omega}(0.5)+P\left(\omega\le \frac{x+1}{2}\right)(1-F_{\omega}(0.5))\\&=F_{\omega}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)F_{\omega}(0.5)+F_{\omega}\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)(1-F_{\omega}(0.5))\end{align*}

Where $$F_{\omega}=\begin{cases}0,&\omega<0 \\ x,&0\le \omega <1 \\ 1,&1\le \omega\end{cases}$$

Now, having $F_X(x)$ you can write $f_X(x)=\dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}F_X(x)$ and find the pdf.